# How to improve performance of app-script that creates 60 sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a simple app script in Google Sheets that uses the `insertSheet` method. It loops an array, and thus creates 60 sheets. The script however is *painfully* slow - taking minutes to complete.

How can I improve the performance of this method? Or is there another way to create 60 sheets in a more performant way - maybe using the sheets REST api?

**Context**

I have a master sheet, that acts like a template. When changes are made to this sheet, it needs to be copied 60 times, so the user does not have to make the change over and over again.

**CurrentCode**

```js
var listOfSheetsToCreate = ['1', '2', '3', ... '60'];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('templateSheet');

listOfSheetsToCreate.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    ss.insertSheet(sheetName, ss.getNumSheets(), {template: templateSheet});
});
```

Comment: is your primary concern that the script takes a long time, or that the user has to wait while the script completes?  Would a solution that creates the sheets  slowly, in the background, while giving the user quick feedback, work?

Comment: Use the REST API to `batchUpdate` and create all 60 sheets at once

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? You want to overwrite 1 sheet to the existing one Spreadsheet which has 60 sheets. Or you want to put 60 sheets to the existing one Spreadsheet as new sheets. Or you want to overwrite 1 Spreadsheet to 60 existing Spreadsheet? Or you want to copy 1 Spreadsheet to 60 Spreadsheet by creating new Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about your goal? I think that if you can provide your current script, it will help thinking your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I added the current code, hope it answers your question

Comment: @tehhowch Do you have any resources/guide on how the request payload should look like? It's my first time using this API endpoint.

Comment: @CameronRoberts I don't like the background solution so much, because that still means the user has to wait - if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After getting comments and feedback, I did some experiments:

1. Duplicating 60 sheets with app-scripts takes around **80 seconds**.
2. Duplicating 60 sheets with the Sheets REST API endpoint [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) takes around **10 seconds** - (and around 1 second to delete the 60 sheets). Using the request body method [DuplicateSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#duplicatesheetrequest)
3. Running the batchUpdate through Advanced Google Services. The execution time is slightly longer - **around 15 seconds**, but the script is so much more simple - thanks to @Tanaike. This was the solution I ended up using -to solve my problem. I should probably also mention, that running the script actually causes Sheets to reload in the browser - I don't know why. But when it's reloaded, all sheets are created.

I still think that 10 seconds is slow, so if you have any ideas of improving this performance please let me know. I have provided my code, for inspiration below. Really looking forward to some modern javascript...

**Sheets REST API Node.js Code**

```js
export async function batchUpdate() {
    // moved authentication to another method.
    const authObect = await getAuthenticated();

    // The batchupdate endpoint needs the sheet id of the template sheet, so that's why we need the following code
    const ssInQuestion = await sheets.spreadsheets.get({
        auth: authObect,
        spreadsheetId: <spreadsheetId>
    });
    const masterSheet = ssInQuestion.data.sheets.find(v => v.properties.title.toLowerCase() === 'master');
    if (!masterSheet) {
        throw new Error(`Could not find master sheet in spreadsheet, will now exit!`);
    }

    // If we want to delete, the requests to the batch update should look like this:
    // const requests: sheets_v4.Schema$Request[] = ssInQuestion.data.sheets
    // .filter(v => v.properties.title.includes(' - test'))
    // .map(v => v.properties.sheetId)
    // .map(v => ({
    //     deleteSheet: {
    //         sheetId: v
    //     }
    // } as sheets_v4.Schema$Request));

    const requests: sheets_v4.Schema$Request[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        requests.push({
            duplicateSheet: {
                sourceSheetId: masterSheet.properties.sheetId,
                newSheetName: `${i} - test`
            }
        })
    }
    const batchUpdateOptions: sheets_v4.Params$Resource$Spreadsheets$Batchupdate = {
        spreadsheetId: <SpreadSheetIdInQuestion>,
        auth: authObect,
        requestBody: {
            includeSpreadsheetInResponse: false,
            requests
        }
    }
    let start = new Date()
    await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateOptions);
    let end = +new Date() - +start;
    console.info('Execution time: %dms', end)
}
```

**Advanced Google Services App Script**

```js
// I ended up with something that looks like this:
function deleteListOfSheets(listOfSheets) {
  if (listOfSheets.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var deleteRequests = listOfSheets.map(function(v) {
    return {
      deleteSheet: {
         sheetId: v.getSheetId()
      }
    }
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
            includeSpreadsheetInResponse: false,
             requests: deleteRequests
        }, ss.getId())
}

function createListOfSheets(listOfSheetNames, templateSheetId) {
  if (listOfSheetNames.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("List of sheets to create had 0 length, will now exit")
    return;
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Create the array of 'create requests'
  var createRequests = listOfSheetNames.map(function(v) {
    return {
      duplicateSheet: {
         sourceSheetId: templateSheetId,
         newSheetName: v
      }
    }
  });
  // Finally dispatch!
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
            includeSpreadsheetInResponse: false,
            requests: createRequests
        }, ss.getId())
}
```

Comment: I think that the flow of your script is the fastest way of the current situation. By the way, you can also use Sheets API by Google Apps Script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Comment: Hi @tanaike - ok, I have to live with a execution time around 10 seconds it seems like  Regarding the link - does this mean that I can use the Sheets REST endpoints, from inside my Google Apps Script - if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. Although you can directly request the endpoint using UrlFetchApp, I think that to use Advanced Google Services will become simpler script. For example, `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateOptions)` of googleapis with Node.js can be modified to `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)`. At that time, please modify `resource`. If you need a sample script, feel free to tell us.

Comment: I think that this is a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, consider using a template spreadsheet with the 60 sheets already created, you could then  simple use copy() on your template sheet to create a new spreadsheet, then work within that new copy.

Comment: The use case does not permit this. I will update the question with more context.